# Facebook app request dialog height extends well past canvas content height in mobile Safari

Tags: facebook, ipad, dialog, mobile-safari, apprequests

We are using the following code to generate a Facebook app request dialog in our Facebook canvas app.

```
var options = { 
method   : 'apprequests',
message  : 'MESSAGE',
title    : 'TITLE'};

FB.ui(options, function() {alert("called back");});
```

When we make this call in *mobile Safari* on an iPad, the height of the app request dialog extends well beyond the height of the canvas, so that the user scrolls down to see a very long dialog on top of a blank background toward the bottom of the page.

Please note that this does not occur in the *Facebook iPad app* itself, only when accessing facebook.com through mobile Safari.

I've tried calling FB.ui with the 'touch' option - doesn't help.

I've tried calling FB.ui with the 'iframe' option and an access_token - I get a 191 error which I haven't been able to figure out how to fix.

I've made various attempts to set styles for the DOM elements that I can see make up the app request, but this isn't working.

I've tried to use

```
FB.Canvas.setSize($('body').height())
```

to force the size of the canvas in the hopes that the overlaid dialog would respect it, but no such luck.

The other approach I've considered is attempting to manipulate some of these DOM elements in the app request dialog, but this is not looking promising.

Height setting on this canvas app. is "Settable". Changing it to "Fluid" doesn't help.

Any help is appreciated.
Wes

Update - 12/19/11: The following bug is now being worked on by Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/255079837889099

Comment: Seems they wont work on it. Any other hacks available?